# Wordpress won't display navigation menu on all pages

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html

I am working on a project, and I have a great start, but I need one major thing before I can show people/ give a demo.

My project: [enter link description here](http://mci-america.com/)

On the home page (index.php) it looks fine, and how it should look for right now. When you click on the other pages (About, FAQ, Epayments ETC....) it will not display the menu bar with links to the left side.

I thought something like this would work well for it:

```
/* Single post single.php CSS file */
#content {
background:#b4d2f7;
float:right;
position:relative;
width:55%;
height:25%;
right:25%;
}

#content li {

}

#content ul {

}

#content .menu {
background:#123456;
position:relative;
float:left;
width:50%;
}
```

But it didn't work at all, didn't move or change anything (Yes I am sure I called the divs correctly)

This is what displays the current text on all the pages:

```
<article id="content">
     <?php get_template_part( 'nav', 'above-single' ); ?>
     <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
     <?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?>
     <?php comments_template('', true); ?>
     <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
     <?php get_template_part( 'nav', 'below-single' ); ?>
 </article>
```

I really don't know much PHP, this has been a huge learning process for me, so if you can please post links to anything that will help. If you post code, I would like some comments even if they are vague.

Comment: It looks like its a PHP issue, not CSS. Probably a problem with get_template_part() calling the nav-above-single.php. It's hard to debug this when we can't see the rest of the files.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Comment: Maybe not all pages use the same template

Comment: `<?php if ( is_paged() ) { ?>
<div id="nav-above" class="navigation">
<div class="nav-previous">
 <?php next_posts_link(sprintf(__( 'older articles %s', 'blankslate' ),'<span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>')) ?></div>

<div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link(sprintf(__( '%s newer articles', 'blankslate' ),'<span class="meta-nav">&laquo;</span>')) ?></div>
</div>
<?php } ?> ` Is the nav-above.php

Comment: `<div id="nav-above" class="navigation">
<div class="nav-next">
<?php next_post_link( '%link', '<span class="meta-nav">&laquo;</span> %title' ) ?>
</div>

<div class="nav-previous">
<?php previous_post_link( '%link', '%title <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>' ) ?>
</div>
</div>` is the nav-above-single.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using a template for the specific page. If you create a new PHP file and put something to the effect of...

```
<?php
   /*
   Template Name: Main Page
   */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content" class="widecolumn">
    <div style="width:100%;">
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This should create a new template that has the header, if it doesn't go into your theme code and take a look at that and see what's different between the 2 templates. Most commonly the templates are pretty easy to identify, one my might be homepage-template.php or something to that effect. The `get_header()` function essentially is telling wordpress to get everything in the header, this should be the stuff that is common across all pages in the header.php. I have a feeling for some reason it's not pulling the navigation the way that it should be. I've been working on my own theme and the code that I have above works just fine to pull the navigation. You can also go into the `appearance > menus` on the wp-admin. This is where you can find the different navigations that your themes allow. If this doesn't work then let me know and I'll be happy to give it another try, either that or if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the details! I didn't go through the appearance>menus to create the navigation... I did it strictly through the code in the index.php. I thought I could just create a <div> inside of the single-post.php and it would list it with ease, but I was really wrong, do I have to completely redo what I have? Or could I go about and hard code it in?

Comment: I would try to avoid hardcoding it at all costs. What I would recommend doing is looking into doing some stuff such as [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu). If you do a google search for wordpress navigation you should be able to find lots of codex or tutorials on how to actually call the function as well. The navigation is aside from the code that you provided in your example. What are the other templates the theme has? If you go to create a new post you should see different options on the right in a drop down menu.